# Erro de parâmetros no MySQL com C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, parâmetros

```
string sql = @"UPDATE ivendas SET nritem=(@rank:=(@rank+1)) where id_venda = 20";
try
{
    MySQLBase basemysql = new MySQLBase();
    MySqlCommand cmd = basemysql.connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank",0);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    basemysql.Closer();
}
catch (Exception erro)
{
    string teste = erro.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(teste);
}
```

Lembrando que meu RANK e meu contador. Por isso um parâmetro ou variável.

Meu erro e esse daqui ->

> "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near ':=(0+1)) where
>   id_venda = 20' at line 1\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId)\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&
>   affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force)\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   em
>   Restaurante.Ivendas.OrganizarItensdaVenda(String idvenda)"

Meu banco

```
nritem | id_venda 
 2     | 20
 3     | 20
 4     | 20
```

Preciso que fique assim:

```
nritem | id_venda 
 1     | 20
 2     | 20
 3     | 20
```

Comment: o valor de `nritem` vai ser igual ao valor `parametro := parametro + 1` ? o que você quer fazer com isso ?

Comment: não seria apenas: `nritem= @rank + 1`

Comment: Ja coloquei no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: veja se minha resposta ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após o AP esclarecer melhor a resposta teria que ser diferente do abaixo:

Não é possível sem algum truque com o próprio SQL. Poderia usar uma *stored procedure* que tenha uma variável que vá sendo incrementada. Ou poderia usar uma tabela temporária auxiliar que pegue os valores já incrementados.

E não precisaria parametrizar a consulta.

Talvez possa fazer algum alguma [função de janela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_window_function), mas não sei o quanto o MySQL é capaz de lidar om isto ou como fazer já que não tenho experiência este mecanismo.

---

Provavelmente quer isto:

```
@"UPDATE ivendas SET nritem = @rank + 1 where id_venda = 20"
```

Porém, se o valor for 0 mesmo, então faça isto, e nem precisa de parâmetros:

```
@"UPDATE ivendas SET nritem = 1 where id_venda = 20"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/Update.cs).

Esta captura de exceção não faz sentido aí, só causa problema, e o fechamento da conexão desta forma pode causar problemas em algumas situações. [Falo disto o tempo todo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D).

Comment: Não, o rank e um contador @rank:=(@rank+1) toda hora que encontrar uma linha vai acrescentar.

Answer (score 1):

Tente com o seguinte código:

```
  update itens set nritem = 
  ( 
      select 
          aux.iterator 
      from (
          select
          @i:=@i+1 AS iterator,
          nritem,
          venda
          from itens, (SELECT @i:=0) AS foo
          where venda = 20) as aux 
      where aux.venda = itens.venda 
      and aux.nritem = itens.nritem)
  where venda = 20;
```

Antes da execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcd41/1

---

Após a execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c0b6d/1

Comment: qual erro acontece ?

Comment: versão do mysql ?

Comment: agora foi, como havia falado, windows functions só nas versoes acima da 8

Comment: não tem problema, só executar igual está fazendo. Você pode fazer passando como parâmetro, o número da venda por exemplo, ou nenhum parâmetro, e deixar o número da venda dentro da query, ou até mesmo não passar o número da venda e alterar todas de uma vez só

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Parameter '@i' must be defined.\r\n   em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName, Int32 parameterIndex)\r\n

Comment: o problema e o @i ele e um parâmetro e não uma variável.

Comment: entendi, vou pesquisar como faz dentro do MySqlCommand